# Check if a class exist in a file

Tags: php

I want to create a little function with to parameters : "class_name" and "file_name".

This function will return "True" if a class with the name given exists in the file given else "False".

I do not know how to do that.

Comment: I guess you have to write some code?! Just *try* it until you fail. You can also start with pseudo code! (<- Just show some effort!)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`class_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php):

```
class_exists('class_name');
```

It will check if the class has been defined and it return a `boolean`.

And about the function you are asking you should mention how you want to do this and what is the purpose.

**update:**

```
token_get_all(file_get_contents('index.php'));
```

will return all the tokens from a particular file. Then you can check the returned array for class existance. [token_get_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php)

Comment: For that he has to include or require the file before that, and maybe he doesn't want that (but he doesn't say anything about that) :) And i would (personally) remove the echo :)

Comment: I already know this function but i think it does not allow me to check if the class exist in a given file.