# In PHP how can i check if class exists?

Tags: php, class, struct

So i have this kind of struct function in main class

```
function __construct(){
    $this->conf = $GLOBALS['conf'];
    $this->dbi = new dbinfo;
    $this->modOpt = new modOptions;
    $this->lang = new language;

    /** Connect DB extended Class **/
    parent::__construct($GLOBALS['connect']);
}
```

where i define classes, but this classes is into library file which is included at the start of file except one, which is included when post request will appear like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['delGroup']) && isset($_SESSION['content_viewer']) && $_SESSION['content_viewer']['code'] >= 1){   
    include_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../..')."/mod/dbinfo/proc.php");
}
```

so i want add check into my construct function for dbinfo class like this

```
function __construct(){
    $this->conf = $GLOBALS['conf'];
    if (isset(new dbinfo))
        $this->dbi = new dbinfo;

    $this->modOpt = new modOptions;
    $this->lang = new language;

    /** Connect DB extended Class **/
    parent::__construct($GLOBALS['connect']);
}
```

but this method with `if isset` does not works, please show me correct way how to check if class exists into file. thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php ?

Comment: Is there something ironic about the fact that PHP has a function actually called `class_exists()` ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php ... I can almost guarantee that had you just typed your question title into <search_engine_of_choice> you'd have got this answer and saved yourself a tonne of time writing the question out.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29940289/check-if-a-class-exist-in-a-file

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try using, `class_exists()`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php

In your case, looking for `dbinfo` class do this:

```
      if(class_exists('dbinfo')){
          //do something
```

If your class has a namespace, include the ful namespaced classname.

Comment: please  do not forget use true in case different default settings, use `class_exists('dbinfo', true);`

Answer (score 5):

`class_exists('class_name',false);`

Set `false` to `true` if the function should try too load the class.